# Type error: list indices must be integers or slices, not Symbol

Tags: python, sympy

So, i got this piece of code for my electric circuits problem (coding on `spyder`):

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol, simplify

vo = Symbol("vo") #amplitude of output voltage
vr = Symbol("vr") #amplitude of voltage r
ir = Symbol("ir") #amplitude of R-current
ic = Symbol("ic") #amplitude of C-current
il = Symbol("il") #amplitude of L-current
r = Symbol("r") #resistance
omega = Symbol("omega") #angular frequency
c = Symbol("c") #capacitance
l = Symbol("l") #inductance

eq1 = (vr + vo - 1,
 ir - ic - il,
 vr - ir*r,
 vo - ic/(1j*omega*c),
 vo - 1j*omega*l*il)

sol = solve(eq1, (vo, vr, ir, ic, il))
vos = simplify(sol[vo])
print(vos)
print(sol[vo])
```

that has an output of:

```
l*omega/(I*c*l*omega**2*r + l*omega - I*r)
l*omega/(I*c*l*omega**2*r + l*omega - I*r)
```

which is a `Vo` solution of my current circuit

Then I changed some parts of `eq1` since im going to solve the `Vo` again of another circuit which goes like:

```
eq1 = (ir*(r + 1/ic + il) + vo - 1,
 ir - ic - il - vr/r,
 vr - ir*r,
 vo - ic/(1j*omega*c),
 vo - 1j*omega*l*il)
```

`eq1` is the only part that ive changed, but when I run it, this error shows up:

> ```
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Symbol
> ```

anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: Would it be too much work to tell us where the error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a `print(sol)` line.  With the original `eq1`, `sol` is a dictionary, and `vo` is a valid key:

```
0936:~/mypy$ python3 stack52932207.py 
{vo: l*omega/(I*c*l*omega**2*r + l*omega - I*r), vr: I*r*(c*l*omega**2 - 1.0)/(I*c*l*omega**2*r + l*omega - I*r), ir: I*(c*l*omega**2 - 1.0)/(I*c*l*omega**2*r + l*omega - I*r), ic: I*c*l*omega**2/(I*c*l*omega**2*r + l*omega - I*r), il: -I/(I*c*l*omega**2*r + l*omega - I*r)}
l*omega/(I*c*l*omega**2*r + l*omega - I*r)
l*omega/(I*c*l*omega**2*r + l*omega - I*r)
```

With the newer `eq1`, `sol` is a an empty list, so indexing with `vo` is no longer valid.

```
0937:~/mypy$ python3 stack52932207.py 
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack52932207.py", line 28, in <module>
    vos = simplify(sol[vo])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Symbol
```

I'm not that familiar with `sympy` and `solve`, but my guess is that the new `eq1` no longer has a solution.  In any case, that's what you need to focus on - why does `solve` return an empty list?

And please, when asking about an error, include the traceback.  We need to know where the error occurs, not just what is says.  Once you have an idea of where the error occurs you can add diagnostic prints.  In this case, both location and error message were relevant.

Comment: ohh, that must be it. i'll take note of that.
this was my first time of asking a question here so i kind of don't know what i should add on my question. i'll make sure to add those essentials next time. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the only place where you're trying to index a list is when you call:

```
sol[vo]
```

`vo` is an object of type Symbol, but lists require you to use integers (or slices), as the error suggests. Eg:

```
sol[5]
sol[1:3]
```

So you need to convert `vo` to an integer before using it to index a list.